# dynamic binding of radio checked observable name

Tags: knockout.js

This is my current viewModel

```
Shortconfig = {
  configa = ko.observable('');
  configb = ko.observable('');
  ...
  configN = ko.observable('');
 }
config = ko.observableArray ([ 
  configA = {
    options : [ { 'text':'Option1', 'value': 'O1' },  
            { 'text':'Option2', 'value': 'O2' },
            ....
            { 'text':'OptionN', 'value': 'ON' }
          ],
   image : 'imageconfiga.jpg',
   fieldname : Shortconfig.configa
  }, 

  configb = {
    options : [ { 'text':'Option1', 'value': 'O1' },  
            { 'text':'Option2', 'value': 'O2' },
            ....
            { 'text':'OptionN', 'value': 'ON' }
          ],
   image : 'imageconfiga.jpg',
   fieldname : Shortconfig.configb
  }, 
  ....
confign = {
    options : [ { 'text':'Option1', 'value': 'O1' },  
            { 'text':'Option2', 'value': 'O2' },
            ....
            { 'text':'OptionN', 'value': 'ON' }
          ],
   image : 'imageconfiga.jpg',
   fieldname : Shortconfig.confign
  }
]);
```

in other words I have a series of groups of options;
From that I can generate easily all the radio buttons I need using one single template and use it in as it as div as required to generate the groups of radio buttons I need.

My problem is that each group of radio button must bind to a different field in shortconfig

configa radio buttons must have a data-bind = "value:$root.Shortconfig.configa" and configb radios must have a data-bind = "value:$root.Shortconfig.configb" and so on.

I tried using the **fieldname** entry in each config but I failed miserably and not found how I can do that, as I have not been able to find

1- if it is possible and

2- what syntax I should use,

I can only hardcode this in the template; So having currently 30+ groups of options, I end up with 30+ template just for that one thing.

So my question is it possible and how do I write that ?

Hope I made myself understandable.

Thanks in advance for your time

Didier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y4hskdpu/1/

```
var _Shortconfig = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.configa = ko.observable('');
  self.configb = ko.observable('');
  self.configN = ko.observable('');
}

var Shortconfig = new _Shortconfig();
```

Then this is accessible:

```
fieldname: Shortconfig.configa
```

Comment: Thanks a lot tyler_mitchell for taking the time, this works fine. My data model was in fact quite a bit more complex , and using a template I nneded to get to the parent of the inner loop, which does not seem to work. So knowing that there was a possibility, I moved the fieldname inside the inner array and it now works a treat, goodbye the 30+ templates !!! Thanks a lot

Comment: In fact it seems that it is just the syntax with $parent which was causing an issue; using a template in foreach mode with a 'as' parameter , I was able to   remove the firlname from the innermost array, thus saving a lot of duplication.